# dat file didn't update when using java to writing

Tags: java

i wrote this method and then call it in main class, it actually print success but when i open the file and nothing in it. Further, when i read the file and print out all the content in Profile.dat, it will print the text that i have just written to file but still nothing when i open.

```
public void WriteToFile() {
              try {
                FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter("Profile.dat");
                myWriter.write("Files in Java might be tricky, but it is fun enough!");
                myWriter.close();
                System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
              } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An error occurred.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: As a note, files in Java are not tricky if you do it the right and modern way. First of all, use try-with-resources. Second, dont use the old cumbersome file-io but NIO. `Files.writeString(Path.of("Profile.dat"), "hello world");`, done. Simple.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking at the wrong file. You probably have another file with that name somewhere else, next to the code. Check your relative paths.

Comment: The file is in the current working directory if relative path is used. Use System.getProperty("user.dir") to see this current path.